# sigkill doesn't terminate C program

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm under the impression that `sigkill` always works? I have a signal handler in my program that displays an exit prompt when you press Ctrl-C. That works fine but how do I also make it work when I kill through the command line? Right now the kill command does nothing. Is there something I'm supposed to implement in my code to make kill work?

Comment: `^C` don't send a `SIGKILL`. Use the  `kill -KILL`  command to send it

Comment: When you say "the kill command does nothing", what exactly is the command you're using, and what exactly happens to the process in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set a signal handler for `SIGKILL`.

Your process does not get a chance to respond to `SIGKILL`.  It is unilaterally terminated immediately; the process cannot do any clean up.  The O/S releases the resources allocated to it, just as it does for any other dead process.

See POSIX [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), and [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), and (most particularly) [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) — which says that `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught or ignored.

---

OTOH, you say "how do I also make it so when I kill through the command line it also works".  How do you plan to kill it?  Assuming you have the PID in `$pid`, then:

```
kill $pid
```

sends a `SIGTERM` signal, and you can control which signal is sent by specifying it.  The <kbd>Control-C</kbd> key normally sends `SIGINT`, usually signal number 2.  The other signal sent from the keyboard is `SIGQUIT` (<kbd>Control-\</kbd>) or the various job control signals.

If you use:

```
kill -INT $pid
```

then that sends an interrupt (`SIGINT`) to the process (as would `kill -2 $pid`).  The default is equivalent to `kill -TERM $pid`.  You'd send `SIGKILL` with one of:

```
kill -KILL $pid
kill -9 $pid
```

Answer (score 2):

When you press control-C, that sends SIGINT, which your program can catch.
When you use the `kill` command, that sends SIGTERM by default, which your program can also catch.
But your program cannot catch or ignore SIGKILL. That's the one that's always guaranteed to be able to kill even a misbehaving program.

Answer (score 0):

Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) (for the command) and [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) (for the system call).

By default, `SIGTERM` is sent by the `kill`  command (e.g. `kill 1234` is sending `SIGTERM`, using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), to process of pid 1234). Of course you can give an explicit signal in your `kill` command, e.g. `kill  -QUIT 1234`.  You can catch it (e.g. `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT`) by installing an appropriate signal handler.

Of course, you cannot catch `SIGKILL` (witch you could send with `kill -KILL 1234`  command), so you cannot set a signal handler for it (i.e. `sigaction` would give `EINVAL` error). Sending a `SIGKILL` *always* kills -i.e. terminates- the receiving targeted process (and should be used on rogue processes).

Regarding  <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>  it is a complex thing related to tty-s (generally it is sending a `SIGINT` signal). Read [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/); etc... See also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) & [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)

In practice, take the habit to `kill`  your processes first with `SIGTERM`, then with `SIGQUIT` and at last with `SIGKILL`. Some processes (e.g. database servers) need some time to save a useful state to disk. So don't use `kill -KILL`  at first (some processes might have an inconsistent state for their internal files, give them a chance to manage that with a "gentle" signal)